# cant exit from my application

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I created an application in which database loads on start and after few milliseconds it navigates to Mainpage. My problem is when I click back key from my mainpage the database loads again and comes back to Mainpage,Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you write any code in OnNavigatedFrom() or in OnBackKeyPress() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions. One: load the database in the Application_Launching and the Application_Activated (when e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved == false) event handlers. When doing this, always ensure that MainPage is the page the app navigates to first. Your page can bind to values (from a backing ViewModel) that will change and fire the PropertyChanged event. This will cause the page to display the data.

The second solution is to modify [this implementation](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx) of navigating to a login screen to match your needs of loading the database.

Comment: hi shawn,I overrided onbackpress using below command is this a advisable way?new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit(); using xna.game dll

Comment: Not sure that will pass certification, but worth a shot.

Comment: Calling Exit() will definitely NOT pass certification, so I would advise against doing this.  Shawn's answer is valid and you should work to make sure the database doesn't load again and let the back key do it's normal thing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional Info Gambit!

Answer (score 1):

I overrided onbackpress event using below command and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game dll?

```
new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
```